# How to test activiti framework using automation?

Tags: testing, automation, activiti

I have a workflow engine using activiti framework in my project,I am trying to explore the ways to automate the test cases for testing this apis of workflow engine.Can someone help with same as where should I start with?

Answer (score 1):

We are definitely going in that direction with Activiti Cloud. We are creating a BDD framework based on serenity with operations and assertions based on the BPMN elements present in the process definitions.

We can have a chat in gitter if you like. It will be nice to understand a little bit more what were you thinking your approach will be.

Cheers